# Link Issue in IE

Tags: html, internet-explorer, hyperlink

I have a problem with linking in my site.

I'm using this code

```
<div id="menubutton3">
     <a href="besiktning.html" class="fill"></a>
     <p>BESIKTNING</p>
</div>
```

and it works fine in all browser except IE. In IE I cannot press the link if I press directly at the text, but if you press around the text ( still inside the box ) it works. I'm wondering if there is any way around this?

Comment: for example www.gosab.se

Comment: Why not `<a href="besiktning.html" class="fill">BESIKTNING</a>`?

Comment: Or <div id="menubutton3">
    <a href="besiktning.html" class="fill"><p>BESIKTNING</p></a>
</div>

Comment: If putting the text between anchor tags works fine for you, don't tell me this is a question to be asked in Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

add this

## menubutton3{display:table-cell;}